# How to make two rows in table in html 50% 50% with css?

Tags: html, css

I want that 2 rows in my table are equaly. 50% width one and 50% width second.
Now first row is smaller because there is less text in it.

I need that there will be table on site full 100% width and then left and right row that should be equal. I hope you understand what i mean.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .awesome {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #prostorzaobrazec {
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>
      <th></th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on what you means, but the idea that I got from your question was something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ymdj6gw/5/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      text-align: left;
      width:50%;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    
    .awesome {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #prostorzaobrazec {
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** you have 4 `<th>` in your script, so there is 4 values in one raw.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can divide data in 50% 50% by `columns` and not in `rows`-

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

.awesome {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#prostorzaobrazec {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">Some text</th>


      <th width="50%">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use divs for this, but here is my take on setting the rows to what I believe you are asking:

NOTE: The height of the table can be set to whatever you want, each row will be 50 percent of that value. Added borders to make this easier to see.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #table {
        height: 500px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    #rowOne {
        height: 50%;
        outline-style: dashed;
    }
    #rowTwo {
        height: 50%;
        outline-style: dashed;
    }
    
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
    <table id="table">
        
        <tr id="rowOne">
            <th>
            <p>THis is a short paragraph</p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowTwo">
            <th>
            <p>This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.</p>
            <p>This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.</p>
            <p>This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.</p>
            <p>This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.This is a long paragraph.</p>
        </th>
        </tr>
    
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, I reread your question and I think you mean columns. In this case, just change the height property to width and give each column an id with width set to 50% just like above...

Answer (score 0):

**If it is about having columns of same widths**, then use [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) , else clarify your question :)

It will spray evenly the columns (4 or 2 in demo):

```css
table{table-layout:fixed;}
th {border:solid;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .awesome {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #prostorzaobrazec {
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>
      <th></th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </table>
   <table><!-- empty cells removed -->
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Or are empty cells are to be hidden or shrinked ?

```css
table{table-layout:fixed;}
th {border:solid;}
:empty {width:0;}
/* remove at screen empty cells from second table */
table + table :empty {display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .awesome {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #prostorzaobrazec {
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>
      <th></th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </table>
   <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="left">Some text</th>
      <th></th>


      <th id="right">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

On both examples `th` have a border to be seen and `table-layout` is set to `fixed`
First example removes empty tables from code, second example do not display empty cells or set width to 0.